# AddressBook: How to synchronise contact when we go for "Don't Allow" in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

[image]

I am using AddressBook framework to retrieve contacts. 1st time, alert box appearing with, **DON'T ALLOW** and **ALLOW** .

If I go for **DON'T ALLOW**, later, if I need to synchronise contacts to my app, I go for **Settings --> My APP -->> Contacts** then, make that switch to **Green**.

Immediately, my app getting crash.

**Crash Log:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
    NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); //Thread 1: signal SIGKILL
    }
}
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: please share code of synchronisation and also are you sure it not crash if user 1st time select ALLOW option ?

Comment: s.. ALLOW option,, working fine.... @jay

Comment: Where exactly did it crash? like when trying to access authorization? or after it.

Comment: Immediately, trying to make the above *white switch*  to *green* .

Comment: I dont know wy App getting crash. But, I am gettin de vote.

Comment: Perhaps because you have not provided any code or useful crash info to work with.

Comment: I have edited my question. **Thread 1: signal SIGKILL**  error receiving.

Comment: @McDonal_11 Put breakpoints on (hint: start from AppDelegate), see where the app is crashing, share that code snippet. And share the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's normal and supposed to happen. When the user changes certain security settings, Apple will automatically "crash" any running application relying on these settings. Would your app handle a change in these settings correctly? Most won't.